# DOJO sorting changes width of the column

Tags: css, sorting, dojo

I have a DOJO table in my page. I have some columns and when clicked on a column, the items in the column are sorted in ascending and descending order. The issue is, when I click on a column, sorting is successful but the width of the column is changed. How can I lock the column width even after sorting? Here is the code.

```
<script src='../js/dojo-release-1.8.0/dojo/dojo.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.require("dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid");
dojo.require("dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.Pagination");
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");
dojo.require("dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.Filter");
dojo.require("dojox.data.QueryReadStore");
dojo.require("dojo.parser"); // scan page for widgets and instantiate them
var gridLayout = [ 
    { name: "S. No.", classes: "title",styles: 'text-align: center;', width: "70px",get : siFormatter,filterable: false },
    { name: "Date & Time", classes: "title",field: "date",styles: 'text-align: center;', width: "150px" },
    {classes: "title", name: "Comm Mode", field: "commtype",styles: 'text-align: center;', width: "100px"},
    { name: "IP/Phone No.", classes: "title", field: "devType", fields:['devType', 'name'], formatter:formatLink1,styles: 'text-align: center;', width: "150px"},
    { name: 'Status', classes: "title", field: "statusMessageFull", fields:['statusMessageFull', 'statusMessageColor'], formatter:formatLink,styles: 'text-align: center;', width: "150px"},
    { name: "I/P Voltage (V)", classes: "title",field: "mainsVoltage",styles: 'text-align: center;', width: "80px" },
    { name: "I/P Charging Current (A)", classes: "title",field: "gridchargingcurrent",styles: 'text-align: center;', width: "150px" },
    { name: "I/P Frequency (Hz)", classes: "title",field: "mainsFreq",styles: 'text-align: center;', width: "120px" },
    { name: "PV Voltage (V)", classes: "title",field: "PVVoltage",styles: 'text-align: center;', width: "100px" },
    { name: "PV Current (A)", classes: "title",field: "PVCurrent", styles: 'text-align: center;',width: "100px" },                              
    { name: "O/P Voltage (V)", classes: "title",field: "outputVoltage", styles: 'text-align: center;',width: "100px" },
    { name: "O/P Current (A)", classes: "title",field: "outputCurrent", styles: 'text-align: center;',width: "100px" },
    { name: "O/P Frequency (Hz)", classes: "title",field: "outputfreq", styles: 'text-align: center;',width: "120px" },
    { name: "O/P Energy (kWh)", classes: "title",field: "outputKWH", styles: 'text-align: center;',width: "120px" },
    { name: "Battery Voltage (V)", classes: "title",field: "batteryVoltage",styles: 'text-align: center;', width: "120px" },                                 
    { name: "Battery Discharging Current (A)", classes: "title",field: "batteryCurrent",styles: 'text-align: center;', width: "220px" },
    { name: "Load (%)", classes: "title",field: "loadpercentage",styles: 'text-align: center;', width: "50px" },
    { name: "Cumulative Solar Energy (kWh)", classes: "title",field: "SolarCumKwh",styles: 'text-align: center;', width: "210px"}];
var store = null;


dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    store = new dojox.data.QueryReadStore({
        url : "./dataAlerts.jsp?siteID=<%=siteID%>&groupID=<%=groupID%>&divisionID=<%=divisionID%>&statusID=<%=statusID%>&date=<%=date%>&date1=<%=date1%>",
        requestMethod : "post"
    });
    <%
       if(Configuration.isSolarNMSAdvancedVersion())
       { 
    %> 
     grid1.canSort = function(col){if(col == 1) return false; else return true;};

     <%
       }else{
    %>
   grid1.canSort = function(col){if(col == 1) return false; else return true;};
    <%
       }
    %>
    grid1.setStore(store);
    grid1.setStructure(gridLayout);
});


var lastSearchValue = "";
function doSearch(el) {
    if (el.value != lastSearchValue) {
        lastSearchValue = el.value;
        grid1.filter({
            name : el.value
        });
        grid2.filter({
            name : el.value
        });
    }
}
function siFormatter(index) {
    return ((this.grid.currentPage() - 1) * this.grid
            .currentPageSize())
            + index + 1;
}
 dojo.ready(function(){
       // alert("Dojo version " + dojo.version + " is loaded");

    });
function myTimerforRefresh(){
    store = new dojox.data.QueryReadStore({
        url : "./dataAlerts.jsp?siteID=<%=siteID%>&groupID=<%=groupID%>&divisionID=<%=divisionID%>&statusID=<%=statusID%>&date=<%=date%>&date1=<%=date1%>",
                    requestMethod : "post"
                });
        grid1.canSort = function(col) {
            if (col == 1)
                return false;
            if (col == 5)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        };
        grid2.canSort = function(col) {
            if (col == 1)
                return false;
            if (col == 5)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        };
        grid2.setStore(store);
        grid2.setStructure(gridLayout);

    }

    function formatLink1(value) {
        var url = '<a href="#" onmouseover="'+value[1]+'">' + value[0] + '</a>';
        return url;
    }

    function exportAll() {
        dijit.byId("grid").exportGrid("csv", function(str) {
            dojo.byId("output").value = str;
        });
    };

    function getDelete(item) {
        return "<button onclick=\"location.href='/report?command=delete&reportNo="
                + item + "'\">Delete</button>";
    }

    function formatLink(value) {
        return '<div style="text-align: center; color:white; background-color:'+value[1]+'; font-weight:900;">'
                + value[0] + '</div>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The enhanced grid offer a plugin called Cookie. The Cookie plugin provides a convenient ways to persist grid properties like column width, sorting order, etc, so the grid will look same when the page is reloaded, or when the grid is re-created with the same id.

Have a look here:
https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid/plugins/Cookie.html#id2

**Update with Code**

1. You must set the require:

   dojo.require("dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.Cookie");
2. call the plugin while you setup your Grid:

   ```
   var grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
   id:"grid",
   store:"mystore",
   structure:"mystructure",
   plugins:{
            cookie:{
               cellWidth: true// Do persist column width.
             }
            }
   });
   ```

here' the declarative way to use it:

```
  <div id="grid" data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid"
  data-dojo-props="store:mystore, structure:'mystructure',
     plugins:{
       cookie: /* a Boolean value or an configuration object */{}
  }" ></div>
```

This should keep the cellwidth at it the width it was.

Regards, Miriam

Comment: No, the GridLayout keeps just the iformations about CellTitle,the field it should be connected with and the different cellinformations like style or sortable and so on. Somewhere you must have defined a Grid like in the Code above programatically or If your grid is created declaratively it is inserted into the  data-dojo-props="store:mystore, structure:'mystructure',
  plugins:{
    cookie: /* a Boolean value or an configuration object */{}
}"

Comment: included this plugin in the div(Declarative way). Didn't work.

Comment: I have pagination plugin too. Is that overlapping?

Comment: Have you set the require? dojo.require("dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.Cookie");

Answer (score 0):

After a column is sorted, a little arrow appears in the columns header to indicate that the column is sorted. Keep in mind the arrows width when setting the column width, and everything should be fine.

Comment: how do I fix the width of the arrow?

Comment: Edit the `.claro .dojoxGridArrowButtonNode` rule in `.../dojox/grid/enhanced/resources/claro/EnhancedGrid.css` on line 432(If using dojo 1.9.1). Otherwise check with [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) or something similar, where is the location of this rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting autoWidth = true when grid is defined.